# How to include a timer in a nightly routine for lights?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, tp-link

The use case I'm trying to solve is that after dinner our early teenage kids keep coming into the kitchen and leaving the light on.

We moved into our current home in January and have a collection of leftover mismatched smart products from the last two homes we've had.

***I'd like the kitchen lights to be on a timer, but only after 10pm each night.*** I haven't been able to find a method to do this.

I'm using Alexa, the HS200 switch and the bulbs are 4" sealed recessed LED (not looking to change at this time).

Thanks